# How translate this code from php to python

Tags: python, php, api, translation

Please help me to "translate" this piece of code from php to python. I'm studying the api documentation for one service and I can't understand something. The examples in the documentation are only in php, and I am completely unfamiliar with them. I thank you in advance!

```
    function generate(array $parameters)
{
    sort($parameters, SORT_STRING);

    return hash_hmac('sha256', join('|', $parameters), 'PRIVATE_KEY');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the goal is to return the string of the sha256 hash of the string of a sorted list of parameters joined by `|`, this is my untested implementation.

```py
import hashlib
import hmac

def generate(parameters):
    s = parameters.sort().join('|')
    return hmac.new('PRIVATE_KEY', s, hashlib.sha256)
```